# Simple for -loop not executing but no errors detected either

Tags: python, for-loop

The code doesn't give any result past "print('len_num = ' + str(len_num))" and I have trouble understanding why.
It supposed to be a simple piece of code which converts 1s and 0s into black and white unicode rectangle characters.

```
binary_num = '1011000101010101101101001010101110100010111010101'

len_num = len(binary_num)-1
print('len_num = ' + str(len_num))
squares = ''

for i in range(len_num, 1, 1):
    if binary_num[i] == 1:
        squares += '▮'
    elif binary_num[i] == 0:
        squares += '▯'
    else:
        print('something went wrong')

print(squares)

#▮▯'
```

Comment: Why is `len_num` the actual length minus 1? Does execution actually enter the for loop? Does it exit early? Do some basic debugging here.

Comment: [range](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range)

Comment: Thanks Stuart! also i am an idiot

Answer (score 1):

Usage of the range function is flawed.

Having said that you don't really need an explicit *for* loop for this. One approach could be:

```
binary_num = '1011000101010101101101001010101110100010111010101'
print(binary_num.replace('1', '▮').replace('0', '▯'))
```

**Output:**

```
▮▯▮▮▯▯▯▮▯▮▯▮▯▮▯▮▮▯▮▮▯▮▯▯▮▯▮▯▮▯▮▮▮▯▮▯▯▯▮▯▮▮▮▯▮▯▮▯▮
```